# Loading symbols from simple files

Tags: syntax, raku

This file will be `foo.pm6`:

```
sub bar { "quux" }
say "Loaded";
```

And this one requirer.p6:

```
require "foo.pm6";

say bar;
```

`require` fails silently, not loading foo.pm6, and bar is not found. This also fails:

```
require foo;

say bar;
```

with the same error, about not finding bar. This file:

```
require ::"foo";

say bar;
```

Fails even strangely, with `MVMArray: Can't shift from an empty array`

**UPDATE**: it fails silently because it stops when it finds an unknown symbol, `bar`, so it's not running "It's loaded" before it produces the error. Still, the last error is weird.

```
Undeclared routine:
    bar used at line 9. Did you mean 'bag', 'VAR'?
```

So once that is out of the way, is `bar` actually imported? If it is, in which package name? How can I use it?

Comment: Have you tried `use lib '.'`? See [lib pragma](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pragmas#index-entry-lib__pragma)

Comment: Yep, that works, but that would be my second question, bar is not imported, despite the documentation saying it does so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`lib`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pragmas#index-entry-lib__pragma) to add the current directory to the library search path.

If I add the [`export`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules#Exporting_and_selective_importing) trait to `bar()` in `foo.pm6`:

```
sub bar is export { "quux" }
say "Loaded";
```

the following seems to work (`requirer.p6`):

```
use v6;
use lib '.';
require foo <&bar>;
say bar;
```

**Output**:

```
Loaded
quux
```

Comment: yes I forgot, I added `is export` to `bar()` in `foo.pm6`